# Best Practice for Duplication Code in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 6.7.1

I would like to know best practice for how many percentage of duplication code should be tolerated in a project?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a magical formula providing the maximum acceptable code duplication percentage for all projects.

It does depend on the project, and it should anyway be in direct correlation to some patterns that induce by design some hardly avoidable duplication (eg. entities vs. DTOs, 'Domain A' objects vs. 'Domain B' objects, and such).

In my opinion, such patterns (which depend mainly on the project structure and lanaguage design) should be identified and excluded from analysis, so you can then focus on real duplication and lower it as much as possible.